# Repository Pattern using realm with live objects and internal realm instance handling

Tags: android, realm, repository-pattern

I am trying to implement a repository pattern that use realm and still keep the live objects feature while handling the creating and closing of the realm instances. This my current approach, sadly it does not work. I run all that code on my custom background thread.

```
public Observable<List> getAll(Class clazz) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    SerializedSubject relay = new SerializedSubject<>(PublishSubject.create());
    try {
         realm.where(clazz).findAllAsync().addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults>() {
               @Override
               public void onChange(RealmResults element) {
                      relay.onNext(realm.copyFromRealm(element));
               }
         });
         return relay.asObservable();
    } finally {
         relay.onCompleted();
         try {
            if (!realm.isClosed())
                realm.close();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Background Thread:

```
public class JobExecutor implements ThreadExecutor {

private static final int INITIAL_POOL_SIZE = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
// Sets the amount of time an idle thread waits before terminating
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE_TIME = 10;
// Sets the Time Unit to seconds
private static final TimeUnit KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
@NonNull
private final ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor;

public JobExecutor() {
    threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(INITIAL_POOL_SIZE, INITIAL_POOL_SIZE,
            KEEP_ALIVE_TIME, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(), new JobThreadFactory());
}

@Override
public void execute(@NonNull Runnable runnable) {
    this.threadPoolExecutor.execute(runnable);
}

private static class JobThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private static final String THREAD_NAME = "android_";
    private int counter = 0;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(@NonNull Runnable runnable) {
        return new Thread(runnable, THREAD_NAME + counter++);
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
private <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> applySchedulers() {
    return observable -> observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(mThreadExecutor)) // my background thread
            .observeOn(mPostExecutionThread.getScheduler()); // main thread
}
```

This exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Your Realm is opened from a thread without a Looper. Async queries need a Handler to send results of your query
```

When i use .findAll() instead of .findAllAsync()  this exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can't register a listener from a non-Looper thread or IntentService thread.
```

Thanks in advance and looking forward to your responses.

Comment: What response are you looking for?

Comment: @TimCastelijns
How to create a background thread with a looper. So i can subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(BackgroundLooper))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Thread that has a Looper/Handler, as stated by the IllegalStateException.  Right now, it looks like you're just using the normal Schedulers class, and not the AndroidSchedulers.  Check out this repo for Android specific schedulers.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/tree/1.x/rxandroid/src/main/java/rx/android/schedulers

Comment: I apologize, it missed my mind that i am using my own implementation for the background thread. I have edited my post with the correct implementation. Is there a way to have the same performance with a looper as my custom implementation ? Could you please provide an example for both or either options. thanks again